# ConTeXt and document class

Tags: beamer, luatex, context

Is there a way I can use document class within a ConTeXt project?

I want to produce a project which includes products that I want to "inherit" the beamer class definitions.

Minimal Example:

```
\startproject Lectures
\environment beamerclass
\product Lecture_1
\product Lecture_2
% ... etc
\stopproject
```

Comment: Beamer is a LaTeX package, so it's not available for ConTeXt, which is unaware (not compatible) of LaTeX's document classes, by the way. If you need a Beamer lookalike, you'll need to define it by yourself.  What do you exactly want to do?

Comment: I want to create a project which produces multiple files with the same style. I wonder if such a simple link between predefined LaTeX classes and ConTeXt projects requires to write the whole sty file from scratch. I will be surprised if it is impossible. For example, can't you copy the class sty file into ConTeXt environment in some way?

Comment: I don't get it. Why should ConTeXt support LaTeX packages or document classes? If you need Beamer, use LaTeX. If you need ConTeXt, stop assuming ConTeXt is LaTeX and read relevant documentation (and yes, you'll have to write your own style): https://adityam.github.io/context-blog/post/presentation-40-commits-redux/ Sorry if I sound harsh, but I find baffling your assumption ConTeXt should work with LaTeX stuff. With a simple analogy, you want to play a CD on a gramophone...

Comment: There is a need (and perhaps there is a way to achieve this without ConTeXt) to produce multiple files as a project which inherits the same style definitions. It is impossible in LaTeX (there are multiple questions on the subject). I began to read the ConTeXt documentation lately and think I can utilise it to create a project which produces multiple files which inherit the same style (in my case, the "Beamer" class style). However, if for that purpose I would have to write my own style from scratch, than using ConTeXt is not very efficient for this task.

Comment: What you describe is what the project structure does in ConTeXt: https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Project_structure. There's also modes for conditional output (e.g. screen vs. print versions), etc. However, Beamer itself is unavailable (LaTeX things just don't work in ConTeXt) and you have to write your own environments so different products can be generated with the same style. Long story short: inheritance is supported and, in fact, this is a hallmark of ConTeXt; Beamer (and LaTeX packages in general) isn't

Comment: @DavidCarlisle (1) I hear once and again that LaTeX and ConTeXt are not the same. But it seems to me that they have a lot in common. That is why I call this a "simple link". (2) As far as I read questions on the subject, LaTeX is unable to produce multiple pdf files which are executed with a single click from a 'main' file. At least not complicated files such as presentations which inherit a unified style. If I am wrong I will be happy to learn.

Comment: Oh, for that purpose you only need to enable `--shell-escape` and play with files. In LuaLaTeX it's a bit easier but in principle you could do it with any TeX engine.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I want to have a directory with a 'main' file. Execution of the 'main' file will produce multiple files which would inherit their style from a single sty file. The sty file will contain a preamble which I would modify from time to time. The different presentations will be produced from other tex files which would contain mainly text. The aim is to produce all my lecture presentation with a unified style. When I modify the style, it will take effect on all lecture files at once by compiling the main file. This would save a lot of work hours for me.

Comment: you can have a directory full of latex beamer files and execute `for i in *.tex; do pdflatex $i; done` and get a pdf for each, That loop is written in bash you could write the loop in lua (which is what context wrapper does) or a windows bat file or anything. You could probably even write that loop in context if you want, it doesn't require any connection between the language you write the loop in and latex.

Comment: I did not encounter these simple solutions which are exactly what I was looking for. I believe I understand the command line method and will try it now. However, I wish to study lua, and would appreciate it you could send a link which shows this method, as it is precisely what I was looking for.

Comment: I am afraid the command line method cannot be applied to my question, since in case I wish to change something in the preamble, I would still have to do it manually for each file.

Comment: Well, another solution for you could be to use beamer's `\lecture` and `\includeonlylecture` where you could give the latter from command-line, e.g. using the jobname flag. It would not be too hard to set this up and you would have all changes to the preamble immediately reflected. Otherwise, David's approach works fine but you would have to centralize your preamble and `\input` it in your other files.

Comment: It seems odd that there is no simple solution which does not involve the terminal. I would conjecture that lua code would enable such "one click" which produces multiple output files.